# Is "Property" a reserved word in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I searched at https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com and it seems it is allowed. Can I create a model "Property" then?

Comment: You can and if it's going to be reserved at some point, you'll rename everything.

Comment: thanks @radubogdan